# riak mapreduce "not found" output

Tags: mapreduce, riak

I was trying a function in map reduce which sorts the data and returns it. It works well when all the bucket key pairs in input query exist in the riak cluster. When a bucket/key pair does not exist, it gives an output like below.

`[{"not_found":{"bucket":"newspaper-issue","key":"56276","keydata":"undefined"}}]`

I'm not able to remove this output from the map phase, even when I just `return []` in the map phase, it returns this single object.

My question is how can I avoid this output as it is likely that in the inputs there is some bucket/key missing.

Map function is like this:

```
"language" => "javascript",
"source" => "function(value,keyData,arg){
   return []
 },
"keep"=>true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this was already answered on our mailing list for you but wanted to have the answer available here on SO as well:

There is a builtin JS function to use in your reduce phase to fix this; `filterNotFound()`

```
return  Riak.filterNotFound(your_object_passed_from_map_phase);
```